# Why I cannot access this variable inside this simple function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope, let

Im new to Javascript and I dont understand whats happening how the scope works in the following codes:

```
//Code n°1:

let num = 1;

function test(){
    console.log(num);
}

test()       //As I expected I get in console "1"
```

```
//Code n°2:

let num = 1;

function test(){
    let num = 2;
    console.log(num);
}

test()       //As I expected I get in console "2"
```

But here is the problem:

```
//Code n°3:

let num = 1;

function test(){
    console.log(num)
    let num = 2;
    console.log(num);
}

test()       //I expected to get in console "1" and then "2" but instead I get an error.
```

When I run in my browser the code n° 3 Im getting this error:
*Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'num' before initialization*

If I look at code 1 and 2 I suppose that after running code 3 I will get in my console the number 1 and then number 2. But that isnt happening. Why?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think it's called a temporal dead zone - I assume you do know this doesn't happen with `var` - I also assume you know how var declarations are hoisted - no such hoisting with let (or const for that matter)

Comment: I would have expected the error to be about redeclaring `num`.  Instead the error is about accessing `num` before initialization, which doesn't make sense without some deeper understanding of how JavaScript is interpreted, which I don't have.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript exception "can't access lexical declaration `variable' before initialization" occurs when a lexical variable was accessed before it was initialized. This happens within any block statement, when let or const declarations are accessed before they are defined.

Comment: I am not able to comment above  , but you need to remove the let that causes the redeclaration. That is not allowed in javascript. Code number 2 is working as the redeclaration of the variable does not happen inside a function. The first instance  is outside it then you change its value inside the function which is pretty normal.

Answer (score 1):

When the 'test function' is called, the function body gets executed. When it reaches to 'console.log(num)', it starts to search for the 'num variable declaration' (or 'num assignment' or 'num reassignment) **in the test function scope**. So it finds the variable declaration in the next line. The priority for searching for a variable is:

1. Current Scope
2. Closure
3. Scope Chain

So, when the variable declaration is found i the current scope, searching is not continued to scope chain. (It will not search for num variable in global scope.)

I guess this is the reason of the error, but as I am new to javaScript, I am not completely sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize the variable without **redeclaring**, it will work normally, now if you                    redeclar the variable, then this error will happen with *let* or *var*, because in the same                    scope, it is being called by the previous *console.log()*.
It is not recommended that you re-declare *let* variables, if you need to, don't use the same in previous statement, note                    that if you comment on the first *console.log()*, the code will work again, this occurs                      exactly for the lifetime of the variable within this scope, in this case, *let*

```
let num = 1;

function test(){

    console.log(num)
    let num = 2;
    console.log(num);
}

test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Bacause in javascript functions and variables declared with var are hoisted, moved up to the top of the function/lexical block.

But let keyword respect the lexical flow. It pins variable where it is declared.

console.log try to access a variable that is declared bellow in the flow.
So move up manually your let declaration to be above de console.log or change it to var let num = 2; to let javascript engine move it above all automatically.

```
var num = 1;

function test(){
    let num = 2;
    console.log(num);
}

test()
```

or

```
var num = 1;

function test(){
    console.log(num)
    var num = 2;
    console.log(num);
}

test()
```

or, to get access to global var num, which is shadowed by declarations from test's body, var or let, no matter

```
var num = 1;

function test(){
    console.log(num)
    //let num = 2;
    console.log(num);
}

test()
```